# color/colorscheme

Tags: colorscheme, color, background

As you can see in both the vimrc.plug and vim.rc files they both seem to be working in terms of gruvbox. I have syntax on, but when I type Vim into terminal and start typing or open a specific file all the text comes back in that peach color.

Is there something I have configured wrong or is there something I need to input into Vim to make it work?

[image: that is the vimrc.plug file]

[image: that is the vim.rc]

Comment: when i typed :colorscheme in vim it says gruvbox but still only getting the peach characters no red, green or anything else

Comment: Could you tell us what is the filetype of the buffer where the colonization seems not to be working (what is the result of the command `:set ft?`?)

Comment: i set ft=python and that worked, but for something like cpp it did nothing

Comment: For a c++ file you have to do: `set ft=cpp`. If it doesn't give the color you want a screenshot would help to identify where the problem lay.

Comment: i think i got the problem fixed setting the ft worked for some but i solved the problem regarding cpp thank you for your help once again i truly do appreciate it very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colonization depends of the file type. If you edit a Python script the keywords will be in a special color, the same for javascript but for a different set of keywords.

Vim automatically set the filetype looking at the file extension for most file but you can also set it manually with the command:

```
:set ft=python
```

Comment: ty for your help i appreciate it